# Petite Set for Deterministic Markov Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I am reading the book *Markov Chain and Stochastic Stability* by Meyn and Tweedie, and I came across the definition of petite sets that was used later in chapter 15 to derive some ergodicity result of Markov processes (along with the drift condition).

I wonder if the argument applies to the trivial deterministic Markov process (whether it includes the Banach fixed point theorem as a special case). For example, $X_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}X_n$ with $X_0 \in [-1,1]$. It is clear that this process will converge to the Dirac measure at 0. Does this Markov chain have a petite set?

The definition of petite sets is that: We will call a set $C \in \mathscr{B}(\mathrm{X})$ $\nu_a$-petite if the sampled chain satisfies the bound.
$$
K_a(x, B) \geq \nu_a(B),
$$
for all $x \in C, B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathrm{X})$, where $\nu_a$ is a non-trivial measure on $\mathscr{B}(\mathrm{X})$.

In the above definition, $K_a(x, B)$ is defined as follows:
Let $a=\{a(n)\}$ be a distribution, or probability measure, on $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$, and consider the Markov chain $\boldsymbol{\Phi}_a$ with probability transition kernel
$$
K_a(x, A):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P^n(x, A) a(n), \quad x \in \mathrm{X}, A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathrm{X})
$$

I tried to validate the case when C is the unit interval $[-1, 1]$ as a compact set:
Take any measurable set B as a subset of $[-1,1]$. However, when I consider $\inf_{x\in[-1,1]} K_a(x, B) $, it seems to be always $0$ except for $B$ such that $ 0 \in B$, because $P(x, B) = I_{\{\frac{x}{2}\in B\}}$? Consequently, the only $\nu_a$ I can think of is
$\nu_a(B) =I_{\{0\in B\}}$.

Is there anything wrong with the above reasoning? Does it mean any compact interval containing $0$ is a petite set for this degenerate case?

Answer (score 1):

Right, that $\nu_a$ doesn't work if $C = [-1,1]$. If you take $B = \{0\}$, then, unless $x = 0$,  $
K_a(x, B) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  a(n)  I(2^{-n}x \in B) < 1 = \nu_a(B).$ The left hand side is either $0$ or some $a(k) < 1$.

Then again, if you let $C = \{0\}$, then

$$
\inf_{x \in C} K_a(x, B) = K_a(0, B) = \delta_0(B)
$$
which works. This $C$ is petite but it's not always reachable, depending on your starting measure or state space, but that’s another story.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I see where I was mistaken. If I understand your answer correctly, for such deterministic process, that satisfies the Banach fixed point theorem. The only petite set we can find is its fixed point's singleton set {$x^*$}. The $\nu_a$ is then a probability measure on this trivial probability space. However, along with the Lyapunov function $V(x) = \|x - x^*\|$, we can still have the conclusion that the process is geometrically ergodic (it seems apparent that this function satisfies the drift condition if it is a contractive deterministic mapping)